# problem replacing and splitting string

Tags: apex, string

I am trying to replace a pipe character used as a delimiter in a string.  The string comes back with the pipe as the html entity code like this: `Unassigned&#124;Scheduled&#124;Tech on Site`

Now, I'm trying to replace and/or split this string into a string list, but I can't seem to get the replace or split to work.

```
string s = String.valueOf(params.get('status'));
string newString = s.replace('&#124;', '|');
String[]  strs =  newString.split('|');
```

I get the following result:

`strs (, U, n, a, s, s, i, g, n, e, ...)`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Split in Apex is very similar to Java string split.

the pattern you pass to the split method is not a direct match, its a **REGEX** pattern. so the pipe symbol | is considered as a Regex input and it splits the string into individual characters.

You can use the below code to get thru this

```
newString.split('\\|')
```

here's some other discussions around the same topic

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978901/splitting-a-string-using

and a [blog post](http://www.laceysnr.com/2010/03/string-splitting.html) from Lacey on the same topic